# I have a UIButton subclass that I have set an image to in IB, and strangely about 1/3 of the button won't respond to touch! What's going on?

Tags: iphone, image, interface-builder, uibutton, subclass

As described, I have a UIButton subclass, that I am designing in IB. I have set the button subclass to a UIView, and set an image to the button as well. I have set a UILabel beneath the image, attempting to give it the Finder look. Everything works great, except for the fact that the right 1/3rd of the image won't respond to touch!

It is the strangest thing. The button bounds are set to encapsulate the entire image, but that right 1/3rd won'r respond.

Has anyone seen this before? Does anybody know what's going on?

Thanks

Comment: your app is view based or navigation based. i faced such a problem in navigation based app.

Comment: is there another transparent view in front of the right 1/3? Or maybe your button has been moved outside of it's parent view's bounds?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Right now, I am just in the prototyping stage of a simple view, without navigation at this point. I don't know how there could be another transparent view, but I'll look into the bounds issue. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to set the UIImageView to userInteractionEnabled = NO?

Comment: I don't have a UIImageView, I just have a UIView, and then in that, I have a UIButton, and a UILabel. Turning off user interaction on the UIView didn't quite do what I am hoping for...

Comment: Ok wow. I fixed my problem. I was accidentally setting the frame of the view upon initWithFrame different than what I was doing in IB...

Silly problem. Thanks for your help!